# MS SQL server failover

Tags: sql-server, failover, failovercluster

We have a spring java application that connects to a MS SQL server cluster of 2 nodes (2016 SP2 standard version).

We are testing failover: if a node fails, the application needs 90 seconds before reconnecting to the other node, that will be too much for production.

After reading and reading again the HickaryCP documentation for java, I tried to test this scenario with datagrip: I run a long query (insert a line in a table every 500 ms during 10 minutes) and I get the same issue: the database was unavailable for 90 seconds after 1 node failure.

Maybe the issue is cluster side and not application side...

Is there any SQL server cluster configuration that prevent us to reconnect before 90 seconds?

How can the connection be back before these 90 seconds? is there any caching or default configuration that we should update?

Thanks a lot for your help

**EDIT**

The test was wrong, I updated in comments the issue I am getting:

it reconnects as soon as the 1st node is back. The issue is after a second failover: no connection can be established then (I wait for the 2 nodes synchronization before the 2nd failover)

Comment: Have you conducted a manual failover to see how long it takes your SQL Server to come back online? There's a lot that can be in play here... like the underlying storage, CPU, etc.

Comment: yes, the sql server comes back in about 15 seconds, nodes are with synchronous mode.
the unavailable duration is 90 seconds for all test (this is not an average value), that's why we think it is a configuration parameter

Comment: actually the test seems not perfect, I modified it and I can notice that it reconnects as soon as the 1st node is back. The issue is after a second failover: no connection can be established then

Answer (score 0):

its good to check what does your sql log shows for recovery time as to where the time spent. something Recovery completed for database sdx_sigma (database ID 20) in 2 second(s) (analysis 79 ms, redo 145 ms, undo 817 ms [system undo 0 ms, regular undo 0 ms].) if its transaction related you might see more time being spent in the undo (rollback) process.